# Getting an image using Handler.ashx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ashx

I am currently working on a school project and I'm not sure what is being returned and how to make the data usable. Here is the code:

Default.aspx

```
function GetImage(id) {
        //step k. - code here
        xmlHttpObj = CreateXmlHttpRequestObject();
        if (xmlHttpObj) {
            xmlHttpObj.open("GET", "Handler.ashx?id=" + id, true);
            xmlHttpObj.send(null);
            var image = document.getElementById("ProductImage");
            //the response contains an array of 5419 index
        }
    }
```

Handler.ashx

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {
        int id;
        if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
        {
            id = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            byte[] bufferImg = GetImage(id);
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(bufferImg, 0, bufferImg.Length);
        }
    }
```

GetImage(int id) returns  "(byte[]).cmd.ExecuteScalar();", im not really sure what i am supposed to do with the information that is being passed back. I'm assuming it is the image itself? any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not try

```
function GetImage(id) {

            document.getElementById("ProductImage").src="Handler.ashx?id=" + id;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. I was under the impression of needing to use an xmlHttpObject because I have never done it another way. Its good to get a refresh flash every now and then to remember there is always another way.